# html table refresh using jquery/ajax on search

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have very big page, I will searching using first name, last name, now the page refreshes with user details along with the problem cases he has.

The problem cases section is a simple html table and have from and to date search fields with Search button. On provided from and to dates and on click of Search button, I want to refresh the cases between those dates without refreshing the entire page. Now I am doing it with entire page refresh.

Please help me how should I do with jQuery/ajax without using any external ajax tools. I am using Java/JSP, Struts2. I have everything in backend which returns List of objects required. When I am using below code I get the entire html page as result in "data" variable.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "caseSearch",
            data:"FromDate=" + fromDate,
            dataType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#caseResult").html(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

- The ajax request can be passed to a servlet. In servlet set the response to xml format.

  ```
      response.setContentType("text/xml")
  ```
- Create PrintWriter

  ```
      PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
  ```
- In **out** set the data accessed from database that will be rendered in jsp like

  ```
     <Name>x</Name>
     <Gender>male</Gender>
  ```
- So now the data returned will be in xml format.
- Parse xml using javascript to display appropriately.

  [Parsing XML in JavaScript](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript)

---

[DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) can also be used for this purpose.

[Check this for learning resources for DWR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130365/learning-resources-for-ajax-dwr)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am using struts2 and in my org not allowed to use DWR or other kind.

Comment: If DWR is not alllowed then you can send data as XML from struts action controller as I explained above.